# STI rails has_many on one type

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, activerecord

I have a STI called `Person`, I have 3 types: `Contact`, `User` and `Tenant`. `Contact` and `Tenant` belongs to one organization, so they have an `organization_id` column right in the "people" table.

The issue is that the type `User` may have multiple organizations, so it has a dedicated table named "users_privileges". Currently, the `organization_id` in the table "people" is `null` for the type `User`, since many users have two organizations.

Is there anyway to tell ActiveRecord when I do let say `Person.all`, that for the type `User`, it must not check the column organization_id in the table "people" and look for the has_many in "users_privileges" table?

Comment: Is this a polymorphic association (eg belongs_to :person, polymorphic: true) or Single Table Inheritance?

Comment: You are right, it's STI. I was doing polymorphic stuff while writing it, edited!

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve this by setting the correct relation in each of the subclasses, so you would put a `belongs_to` in Contact and Tenant, while putting one of the `has_many` variants in User.

The result would of course be that if you say `Person.all`, some of the resulting objects would have respond to `#organizations`, and some `#organization`. You can work around this by adding a method `#organizations` to Contact and Tenant, and have it just return the one organzation in an array.